# Passing parameters to modelbinder on action parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wish to use a modelbinder I've made directly on an action method parameter. Such as:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(MyBinder))] string param1)
```

However, I need to pass a string into the binder itself, so I was wondering if you could do something along the lines of:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([MyBinder("mystring")] string param1)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass parameters via the attribute declaration. If you look at the source code for ModelBinderAttribute, you will see that its constructor takes only a type argument, that it has no other properties, and that it is a sealed class. So this road is a dead end.

The only way to get information into the ModelBinder that I know of is the FormCollection itself.

You could, however, make a parent binder type and subtype it for each param value which you intend to use. It's messy, but it would work in the example you give.

Comment: you can get url and query string parameters on POST not just the form collection as you have access to the httpcontext within the model binder

Comment: @monkeylee the modelbinder doesn't provide you a FormCollection but you can just create a new one from Request.Form. FormCollection is just a wrapper. See answer from @haacked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510946/get-formcollection-out-controllercontext-for-custom-model-binder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You should a create class drived from `System.Web.Mvc.CustomModelBinder`, and override the method `GetBinder`. For example, here implementation that takes in addition to a `Type` object, also an object array for model binder constructor parameters:

```
public sealed class MyModelBinderAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of the binder.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The type of the binder.</returns>
    public Type BinderType { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parameters for the model binder constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public object[] BinderParameters { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderAttribute" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="binderType">The type of the binder.</param>
    /// <param name="binderParameters">The parameters for the model binder constructor.</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="binderType" /> parameter is null.</exception>
    public MyModelBinderAttribute(Type binderType, params object[] binderParameters)
    {
        if (null == binderType)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(binderType));
        }

        if (!typeof(IModelBinder).IsAssignableFrom(binderType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "An error occurred when trying to create the IModelBinder '{0}'. Make sure that the binder has a public parameterless constructor.",
                binderType.FullName), nameof(binderType));
        }
        this.BinderType = binderType;
        this.BinderParameters = binderParameters ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(binderParameters));
    }

    /// <summary>Retrieves an instance of the model binder.</summary>
    /// <returns>A reference to an object that implements the <see cref="T:System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder" /> interface.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">An error occurred while an instance of the model binder was being created.</exception>
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        IModelBinder modelBinder;
        try
        {
            modelBinder = (IModelBinder)Activator.CreateInstance(this.BinderType, this.BinderParameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                "An error occurred when trying to create the IModelBinder '{0}'. Make sure that the binder has a public parameterless constructor.",
                this.BinderType.FullName), ex);
        }
        return modelBinder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just a thought, I am looking at needing a similar requirement and I wanted to pass in a castled service.

I wonder if you could use the ControllerContext passed into the Binder and expose the service/property or whever via a property?

Just a thought, I am going to try this now and I will feed back

Rich