# MVC 4 Get Parameters in Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I working on MVC 4 Web Project. And I have a code like tihs,

```
public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, ...)
{
    return View();
}
```

I need a list which this list have only parameters name **NOT VALUE**. Like this (Its sample)

```
List<string> list = { param1, param2, ... }
```

code which you will write me, I will write above the `return View();` code.
How can i write a string List with only this parameters name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where your parameters came from. If this was a GET request, than all parameters passed to it will live in `Request.QueryString` collection, and you should be able to do this:

```
List<string> list = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.ToList();
```

If this was a form post, then you should create a FormCollection object (taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511187/728795)):

```
var form = new FormCollection(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form);
List<string> list = form.AllKeys.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you check first code? Because, ToList() cannot be use after Keys

Comment: @aynakolik, apologies, that should have been `AllKeys` which returns an array